# What's this and how do I Merge them all together into one mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects

[image]

I have all these 'Model's and It makes Blender laggy. I was hoping I could solve it by merging it into one. I tried Ctrl + J but it doesn't work. Can anyone show me some examples of merging it?

Comment: are you sure you can merge objects in the Outliner? Once you've selected every object you want you can go in the 3D view and press ctrl J, I guess it should work. Not sure it will make Blender less laggy as you'll have the same amount of vertices at the end...

Comment: oh ok I'll give it a try .thanks